# ArduinoJson reading `null` from Serial

Tags: serial, programming, json

I have a setup that reads from serial when I sense that there is something to be read (and always assume that what is sent to the arduino is valid json):

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) continue;
}

void loop() {

    if(Serial.available()){
        StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;

        deserializeJson(doc, Serial);

        serializeJson(doc, Serial);
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

Given the following input from ArduinoIDE's serial monitor (Set to `newline` setting, `9600` baud):

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

This produces the following:

```
{"hello": "world"}
null
```

I have two questions:

- Is this setup correct/ how I should be waiting and retrieving json from serial?
- Why the additional `null` input? Looks like there is something still in the serial buffer even after the first iteration?
- <strike>How to detect the second case where the resulting document gets re-serialized as `null`? Comparing to `0`, `NULL`, and `nullptr` seem to not work</strike> Figured this one out, found out about `DeserializationError`

Upon utilizing `DeserializationError`, looks like the `null` parsing had an error of `EmptyInput`

Comment: what is sending the data? ... what is the actual data that is sent?

Comment: The Arduino IDE serial console

Comment: manual input data then .... what are the serial console settings? ... there is more than one setting

Comment: Updated to show setup function

Comment: I said `serial console` settings

Comment: Updated to show settings (newline, 9600 baud)

Answer (score 1):

As observed on your `serial console` settings, it mentions both **newline** and **9600 baud**. Let's break this down:

#### **Issue with Serial Communication**

1. **Partial Payloads**: You are currently assuming that when `Serial.available()` returns `true`, the entire JSON payload has been received. However, due to the nature of serial communication (especially at 9600 baud), data can arrive in fragmented chunks. Invoking `deserializeJson()` on a partial JSON payload can result in incomplete or corrupted data.
2. **End-of-Message Ambiguity**: Lacking a definitive end-of-message marker makes it challenging to discern when a complete JSON payload has been received. For instance, when sending `{"hello": "world"}` from the Arduino IDE's serial monitor, it automatically appends a newline (or a carriage return based on your configuration). This newline is then misinterpreted as another JSON payload, leading to the undesired `null` output.

#### **How you can solve this:**

1. **Use a Delimiter**: Choose a specific character or sequence to act as an end-of-message delimiter. The newline character (`\n`) is a typical choice, especially if data is exclusively sent from the Arduino IDE's serial monitor. Nevertheless, if you anticipate newlines within your JSON data, you might consider another distinct character, like `#`.
2. **Read Until Delimiter**: Adjust your code to continuously read characters from the serial port until the chosen delimiter is encountered. Upon receipt of the entire message, it can then be parsed.

#### **Code Example**

Here's a sample code employing the newline character as a delimiter:

```cpp
const int maxBuffer = 256;
char serialBuffer[maxBuffer];
int bufferPos = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) continue;
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = Serial.read();

        if (inChar == '\n') {  // EOM
            serialBuffer[bufferPos] = '\0';
            processMessage(serialBuffer);
            bufferPos = 0;  // Reset buffer pos
        } else if (bufferPos < maxBuffer - 1) {  // Avoid buffer overflow
            serialBuffer[bufferPos++] = inChar;
        }
    }
}

void processMessage(char* message) {
    StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;

    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, message);

    if (error) {
        Serial.println("Failed to parse JSON");
    } else {
        serializeJson(doc, Serial);
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

This way you ensure the entirety of message is parsed and received and therefore avoiding unwanted `null` outputs.

I hope this helps ^_^